# how to access Company / LLP / Director Master data from MCA site using API

Tags: api

I am unable to access the publicly available data from the Ministry Of Corporate Affairs( MCA ) using an API.

For example, I am trying to access the Company/LLP Master data with the below curl,

```
curl --location 'https://www.mca.gov.in//mcafoportal/companyLLPMasterData.do/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'companyName=' \
--data-urlencode 'companyID=XYZ' \
--data-urlencode 'displayCaptcha=true' \
--data-urlencode 'userEnteredCaptcha=sderfgty'
```

But I got the response,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>

<head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Forbidden</h1>
    <p>You don't have permission to access /mcafoportal/companyLLPMasterData.do/
        on this server.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

I have a few queries related to the above Request/Response,

1. Is MCA provide its own API to access data?
2. If yes, does that paid or free?
3. If not, then we can develop a custom API to access MCA data?

I need to access MCA's publicly available data using API for my project and I don't want to use any third-party platforms which are providing paid API to access data from MCA.

Kindly let me know your suggestion/solution.

Thanks

Comment: Were you abe to solve this.

I too need help I this